# How can I efficiently save a list of random numbers in sets of 3, which i will later be able to access?

Tags: python, oop, random

I have a 3d list to which I am randomly appending the string 'baddie' n number of times - in this case n = 20. I am appending randomly by generating 3 random ints which are used as the indexes to which I am appending to. What i would like is to be able to save these random sets of indexes so I can later manipulate them in my code. I was thinking I could possibly save them to a separate list as the 'for loop' iterates through generating the random values.

```
    class board_works():
        def __init__(self):
            self.a = 2
            self.b = 3
            self.c = 5

            self.board = [[[ [] for _ in range(self.a)]
                         for _ in range(self.b)]
                         for _ in range(self.c)]


        def enemy_set(self):
            n = 20
            for count in range(0,n):
                 randa= random.randint(0,self.a-1)
                 randb= random.randint(0,self.b-1)
                 randc= random.randint(0,self.c-1)
                 self.board[randc][randb][randa].append('baddie') 
                 n = n - 1
                 if n == 0:
                     print(self.board)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the indices of the baddies in a list of tuples.

I've changed the name of your class to make it conform to the PEP-0008 style guide, and added a `__str__` method to make it easier to see the board state. I've also made the random indices selection loop a little more compact.

```
class BoardWorks:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 2
        self.b = 3
        self.c = 5

        self.board = [[[[] for _ in range(self.a)]
                        for _ in range(self.b)]
                        for _ in range(self.c)]

        self.baddies = []

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join([str(row) for row in self.board])

    def enemy_set(self, n=20):
        for count in range(n):
            c, b, a = (random.randrange(u) for u in (self.c, self.b, self.a))
            self.board[c][b][a].append('baddie' + str(count)) 
            self.baddies.append((c, b, a))

# Seed the randomizer so we get repeatable results while testing
random.seed(42)

bd = BoardWorks()
print(bd, '\n')

bd.enemy_set(10)
print(bd, '\n')

# Print the baddies indices
for i, t in enumerate(bd.baddies):
    print(i, t)
```

**output**

```
[[[], []], [[], []], [[], []]]
[[[], []], [[], []], [[], []]]
[[[], []], [[], []], [[], []]]
[[[], []], [[], []], [[], []]]
[[[], []], [[], []], [[], []]] 

[[['baddie4'], ['baddie0', 'baddie8']], [[], []], [['baddie2'], []]]
[[['baddie1'], []], [[], ['baddie7']], [['baddie5'], []]]
[[[], []], [['baddie9'], []], [[], []]]
[[[], []], [[], []], [[], []]]
[[[], ['baddie6']], [['baddie3'], []], [[], []]] 

0 (0, 0, 1)
1 (1, 0, 0)
2 (0, 2, 0)
3 (4, 1, 0)
4 (0, 0, 0)
5 (1, 2, 0)
6 (4, 0, 1)
7 (1, 1, 1)
8 (0, 0, 1)
9 (2, 1, 0)
```

To use the data in that baddies list, we can do stuff like this:

```
c, b, a = bd.baddies[8]
print(bd.board[c][b][a])
```

**output**

```
['baddie0', 'baddie8']
```

Comment: This works exactly right. However can i ask how the 2nd function works :def__str__(self):
        return '\n'.join([str(row) for row in self.board])

Comment: @HamadKashmiri An object's `__str__` method gets called whenever you try to convert the object into a string. By default, the `print` function calls that `__str__` method on each arg so it can get an appropriate string to print. The method I wrote just gets each row of the board, turns it into a string (which ultimately calls each of those lists' `__str__` methods), and then joins all those strings together, with a `\n` (the newline char) between each one.

Comment: So if im correct, in essence the print method is being altered to automatically print self.board like this every time it is printed. Interesting

Comment: @HamadKashmiri Not quite. We aren't changing the behaviour of the `print` function, we're changing the behaviour of the BoardWorks objects. `print` itself doesn't know how to convert _any_ objects into strings, it just asks each object to give it an appropriate string to print.

Comment: @HamadKashmiri (cont) Actually, there's a related method to `__str__` called `__repr__` which returns a programmer-friendly string representation of an object; the `__str__` method is for the user-friendly string. If an object doesn't define `__str__`, when you call `str()` on it (either explicitly or when attempting to print it) then the objects `__repr__` method will get called instead. Every object has a  `__repr__` method: if you don't define one then it uses the one inherited from its parent class. You can also get the result of `__repr__` by calling the `repr()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to use `n` as a counter as you can just print the board after the `for` block. And presumably `randrange` is a better fit for the random number.
Just construct a list of indexes, like you do for the board and then loop of those indexes to assign your `'baddies'`:

```
from random import randrange

...

    n = 20
    self.indexes = [(randrange(self.a), randrange(self.b), randrange(self.c)) 
                    for _ in range(n)]
    for randa, randb, randc in self.indexes:
        self.board[randc][randb][randa].append('baddie')
    print(self.board)
```

Comment: I see, not very familiar with python, i think i see how this works, would printing self.indexes then show a list of all the randomly generated numbers?